# How to set an HTML5 input to required via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, required

I have a form with many input fields and radio buttons.
Some fields must get the required - attribute. But which fields are required depends on which radio button has clicked.

(If "Company-email" is checked -> input field "Company email" is required, otherwise private email)

Initially all field should be `required=false`.
But that does not work. No matter which value I give to the required-attribute, required is always true.

So... how can I set an input-field initially to required=false?

EDIT:

Thank you all for your answers.

In fact nothing works.
I made a test html document like this:

```
function test2()
            {
                document.getElementById("33").attr("required");
            }
<form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="33">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="radio" onclick="test2()">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

It's unbelievable but this very simple example does not work.
The field with id 33 is not a required-field.
I can submit the form and nothing is checked.
What is wrong here?

EDIT 2:

Now I found the solution:

```
function test2()
            {
                document.getElementById("33").required = true;
            }
```

This works for me on my example page. I have to check if i really can work with that in my real project.

Answer (score 1):

`required` is a boolean attribute, so no matter what value you give it will still be required.
Instead of setting attributes you can  set the element property

```
document.getElementById('companyemail').required = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `required` attribute from the fields that are not required.

In HTML5, this is an example of how to use `required`:

```
<input type="text" name="name" required>
```

So chances are that even when setting it to false (or anything, in fact) would be considered true.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#privateemail").attr("required");
             $("#companyemail").removeAttr("required");
    $('#checkbox1').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
             $("#companyemail").attr("required");
             $("#privateemail").removeAttr("required");
        }
        else{
             $("#privateemail").attr("required");
             $("#companyemail").removeAttr("required");
          }

    });
});
```

I hope this may help, let me know your feedback...

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the required attributes

```
your-input.removeAttr( "required" );
```